# Connecting to SSH using JTA in Java

Tags: java, ssh

Can someone give me some example code? I've tried to look for the documentation but it looks confusing..

Or maybe I could use a different library to conenct to SSH in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTA only connects to SSH-1. If you are talking about SSH-2 you need something else, or you need my JTA SSH2Socket class ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've always used [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (a pure Java implementation of SSH2). The [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) illustrate most use cases.